# CSS BEM children of a modifier

Tags: css, bem

I'm new into BEM methodology, and I have a question targeting a child of a modifier.

Lets say I have this HTML:

```
<div class="block-container">
    <div class="block-container__element"></div>
</div>
```

At `block-container` I add a modifier `block-container--modifier`.

And the CSS would be:

```
.block-container {
    ...
}
.block-container__element {
    ...
}
.block-container--modifier {
    ...
}
```

And my question here is: how I can change some CSS attributes of the `__element` when the modifier is applied?

As far as I read, we have to avoid using nested children, but I think that sometimes that rule must be broken to achieve this kind of things, I'm right?

I'm using pure CSS, no LESS, no SASS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general cascades should be avoided, but not in this case.

If you are sure that the block `block-container` is never recursively included in another `block-container`, then you can do:

```
.block-container--modifier .block-container__element {
}
```

Otherwise you have to put another modifier on the element: `block-container__element--modifier`.

There is a third solution but it is unorthodox. In some case, I suggest to use the child selector if you are sure that, at the DOM level, the element is a direct child of the block (for example if the block always is a `<ul>` and the elements are the `<li>` children). Then you can do:

```
.block-container--modifier > .block-container__element {
}
```